# Using search_api and search_api_views how do I display images?

Tags: views, commerce, search

Drupal-7. search_api_solr 7.x.1.4 search_api_views 7.x-1.11

I have an index of documents and associated commerce products. The commerce product has an image in it. I can get views to display an index of the image url, but not display the images.

The image is displayed fine with a sql backed (non-solr) view.

[image: Image field views configuration]

[image: Views fields with preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated ctools to 7.x-1.4 and it started working.